# Grub installation failed on HP Laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 17.10 on a HP laptop (Model:HP14bs547TU) as dual boot with Windows 10. Every time installation fails at the grub installation stage. It is giving me the following message

> The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot.

I've never faced this kind of issue previously. How can I overcome it? Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried boot-repair from a live cd ?

Comment: No. How to do it? I'm trying to install using a USB Disk.@An0n

Answer (score 1):

**Boot Repair should fix this.**

Use a live disk to boot.
Then in a terminal enter following commands :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Click on Recommend Repair to fix the boot issues.

[image: Boot-Repair]

Comment: This solution works for me partially. But now I can only login to Linux. There is no way to login to windows now!!!